# Label text not wrapping in a Bootstrap grid setup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get labels to not wrap in Bootstrap3 but can't seem to get it to work.

I tried placing 'word-wrap: break-word' even on the label but that doesn't seem to break the label's sentence either.

I did see in the documentation to 'Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing.' but I cannot use 'form-group' i think if I want to use bootstrap divs to control grid/form layout of the labels/answers separately (the labels/inputs are more mobile friendy and expand to 100% of the screener when on xs screens, but on sm+ screen the labels show up left of the input to save screen space).

Here is an example... Expand the jsfiddle's right side frame very big and then you see the form labels get placed on the left with right text-alignment and the issue occuring then.

http://jsfiddle.net/armyofda12mnkeys/nud64aq7/

Pic below of the 3rd label which doesn't wrap:
[image]

Here is the basic code I use for that label/input setup:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4  label">
    <label for="firstname">House Number and Street and longer label and longer label and longer label and longer label and longer label </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 answer">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your house # here" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you look through the DOM elements in your Fiddle you will see this code for the `label`:

```
.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

Just remove the property or overwrite the `white-space: nowrap;` or set the property to `normal`

**Update 1.0**: Just to clarify this CSS property only exists in Bootstrap v3. In v4.x the `white-space` property has been removed from `label` elements.

**Update 2.0**: People have been asking about BS v4.1 and looking through their code the `label` wraps like normal text and doesn't not contain a `white-space` property. However I did notice in the input group section that some of the classes being used do contain `white-space: nowrap` (i.e. `input-group-text` class). The fix would be the same, overwrite the property in a separate file or edit that specific class to use `white-space: normal`. If its happening in a different section that I dont see let me know in the comments and I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: Cool thanks for the explanation, I didn't realize Bootstrap was adding styling code for .label).

Comment: So how would you do it in Bootstrap v4.x

Answer (score 7):

Are you trying to make the text *wrap?*
If so, add

```
    white-space:normal;
```

to the label class.

http://jsfiddle.net/kswdusL6/

Answer (score 4):

add this to the label

```
label {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

example working:
http://jsfiddle.net/nud64aq7/4/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add  'text-wrap' class to your element